# PDO rowCount() error when calling its object from extended classes

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database class that I made that uses PDO to connect to my queries, I'm calling it in my main classes constructor as an object.

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $db;

    public __constructor()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }
}
class Themes extends MyClass
{
    public $avatar;
    public $theme_name;
    public $theme_by;
    public $theme_by_email;
    public $theme_by_website;
    public $theme_description;
    public $theme_thumb;
    public $theme_source;
    public $theme_css;
    public $theme_js;
    public $theme_uploaded_on;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->get_theme();
        $this->get_avatar();
    }

    public function get_theme()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM `user_themes`
                WHERE `user_id` = " . $this->session->get('user_id');
        if($this->db->row_count($sql))
        {
            $result                  = $this->db->fetch_row_assoc($sql);
            $this->theme_name        = $result['theme_name'];
            $this->theme_by          = $result['theme_by'];
            $this->theme_by_email    = $result['theme_by_email'];
            $this->theme_by_website  = $result['theme_by_website'];
            $this->theme_description = $result['theme_description'];
            $this->theme_source      = $result['theme_source'];
            $this->theme_css         = $result['theme_css'];
            $this->theme_js          = $result['theme_js'];
            $this->theme_uploaded_on = $result['theme_uploaded_on'];
        }else{
            die('no results');
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I include my extended classes that calls the constructor of MyClass then I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in db.class.php on line 98
```

which points to this line in my db.class.php

```
class Database {

    private static $PDO;
    private static $config;

    public function __construct() {

        if (!extension_loaded('pdo'))
            die('The PDO extension is required.');

        self::$config = config_load('database');

        self::connect();

    }
...
    public function row_count($statement)
    {
        return self::$PDO->query($statement)->rowCount(); //Line 98
    }
}
```

If I comment out parent::__construct() from my extended classes then I'm ok and get no errors.

Try my site in FireFox, Chrom, Opera, and Safari

http://www.helixagent.com

I seem to be ok in Firefox 3.6 but all those other browsers throw me the error I mentioned...

Comment: I'm getting the error... (Firefox 4.0)

Comment: Are you calling the method twice? According to php.net, this may fail: http://be2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your row_count-method to this:

```
public function row_count($statement)
{
  self::$PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  try {
    $stmt = self::$PDO->query($statement); 
    $result = $stmt->rowCount();
    return $result;
  } catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }

    return false;
}
```

Now you'll at least get an idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This extract is from here (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

> What is the difference between  $this  and  self ?
>
> Inside a class definition, $this refers to the current object, while  self  refers to the current class.
>
> It is necessary to refer to a class element using  self, and refer to an object element using  $this .

Therefore in your function row_count(...) you should use $this->PDO->query(...

[EDIT]

You could try declare $this->db = null; in your child classes before you call your parent class construct.

```
class MyOtherClassB extends MyClass
{
    public __construct()
    {
        $this->db = null;
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Comment: I use self:: because I have a private static variable of $PDO that I'm passing the reference to

Comment: Can you give me an example as to where you mean for me to place the null at?

Comment: Is your declaration of $PDO within db.class.php?

Comment: no, didn't seem to null out the variable. Its just so weird, is it because I'm calling the Database object 2 times when I include my child classes?

Comment: I think the problem has to do with how you have initiated $PDO. Try separate return self::$PDO->query($statement)->rowCount() into $result = self::$PDO->query($statement); return $result->rowCount();

Comment: You know what, it just dawned on me that this isn't an issue in Firefox, but I get this error with Chrome, Opera, and Safari

Comment: PHP is server-side, this can't have anything to do with browsers. Maybe the page is cached somehow? Can you post some more code? Like an example how you create the objects and invoke the row_count($statement)-method would be nice.

Comment: I know what your saying, but I didn't know I had this problem until I tried to look at my site with my iPod, then after seeing the error I tried to look at it in Safari, then Chrome and Opera. Also I posted a snapshop of what my class looks like

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor should be called `__construct()`, not `__constructor()`. So your code likely fails when calling the parent constructor.

Also, when the query()-method fails, false is returned instead of an object on which you can invoke rowcount() on. You should add a check to see if the query is successful.

Comment: hmmmm, are you referring to my child class or my db.class when making the query()-> ?

Comment: I'm referring to MyClass for the constructor part. For the query()-method, I'm referring to your row_count($statement)-method.